# Transforming mean-absolutes to mean differences for meta-analysis

Tags: data-transformation, meta-analysis

For a meta-analysis project, I have been tasked to submit data in Reviewmanager software. 
However, often I come across papers that report on average `pain` or `disability` scores, with respective SD. or S.E., from baseline and multiple time points post-treatment. However, I need to transform this data, to a mean change over time with an SD. Is there any possible way to transform this data as such?

For example; 
Treatment group:
Pain score: Baseline average: 51.47 SD: 15.62 N:29, at 4 weeks: average: 43.25 SD: 16.68, n:27
How can I calculate the mean change with respective SD between these two-time-points; if possible at all?

Comment: You also need an estimate of the correlation between the time points. If, as in the example you quote, they have reported on different samples at the two time points because of drop-out then I think you may have no way forward.

Comment: We usually calculate the 'change from baseline' score (and SD) in Excel. Cochrane has a good explanation and examples: handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_16/… (former handbook) and training.cochrane.org/handbook/current/… (current handbook - you may need to register).